# check to see if lists contain same elements

Tags: python, list

I have a list

```
List1 = [(12,34),(12,6),(2,4),(1,3),(34,32),(34,6)]
```

and another list

```
List2 = [(12,34),(12,6),(2,4),(1,3),(34,32),(56,12),(78,23),(23,56)]
```

I want to create a new list, check the elements of the first against the elements of the second. Editing the second list basically. This list would become

```
List3 = [(56,12),(78,23),(23,56)]
```

Comment: It's always lists with you John, isn't it? :)

Comment: John Smith I don't understand you ask a slight variant of almost the exact same question every time... It seems like this site is not benefiting you at all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If order/duplicates don't matter:

```
>>> A = [(12,34),(12,6),(2,4),(1,3),(34,32),(34,6)]
>>> B = [(12,34),(12,6),(2,4),(1,3),(34,32),(56,12),(78,23),(23,56)]
>>> set(B).difference(A)
set([(78, 23), (56, 12), (23, 56)])
```

Otherwise, if order does matter, just use a list comprehension check membership of a set (O(1) amortized membership checks):

```
>>> set_A = set(A)
>>> [x for x in B if x not in set_A]
[(56, 12), (78, 23), (23, 56)]
```

Keep in mind that this simple solution also works:

```
>>> [x for x in B if x not in A]
[(56, 12), (78, 23), (23, 56)]
```

It will just have to potentially scan through the entire list `A` every time it checks `x not in A`.